# Microsoft Access: run time error 3464 data type mismatch

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database that worked perfectly before, but today for some reason it has this error:

> run time error 3464 data type mismatch

When I click debug, it pointed out the line that has the error:

```
Set rst = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

How could I fix it? Thank you!!!!

Below is my code:

```
Function DmdQtyThruDate(ItemVar As String, DatePeg As Date) As Double
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    strSQL = "SELECT Sum(TotQty) AS TotTotQty "
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM ("
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT DISTINCTROW Sum([dbo_apsplan].[qty]) AS TotQty "
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM [dbo_apsplan] LEFT JOIN [dbo_job_sch] ON (([dbo_apsplan].[ref_line_suf] = [dbo_job_sch].[suffix]) AND ([dbo_apsplan].[ref_num] = [dbo_job_sch].[job])) "
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE ([dbo_apsplan].[item]='" & ItemVar & "' AND [dbo_apsplan].[is_demand]=1 AND DateValue(IIf([dbo_apsplan].[ref_type]='j',[dbo_job_sch].[start_date],[dbo_apsplan].[due_date]))<=DateValue(#" & DatePeg & "#)) "
    strSQL = strSQL & "UNION ALL "
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT Sum([qty_ordered]-[qty_shipped]) AS TotQty "
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM [dbo_coitem] "
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (([item]='" & ItemVar & "') AND ([ref_num]is null) AND ([stat]='o' Or [stat]='p') AND (DateValue([due_date])<=DateValue(#" & DatePeg & "#)))); "
    
    Set rst = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If rst.EOF = False Then
       DmdQtyThruDate = Nz(rst("TotTotQty"), 0)
    Else
        DmdQtyThruDate = 0
    End If
    
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Can you run it again without the `()` after `CurrentDB`? It's been a while since I did VBA in ms-access, but that feels wrong.

Comment: Thank you JNevill, I did it but it still has that error. It wouldn't go away :(

Comment: Post the resulting SQL.

Comment: Try adding a space in `([ref_num]is null)` so `([ref_num] is null)`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using parameterized stored queries which is more efficient than VBA run queries especially with `JOIN` and `UNION` since Access engine saves best execution plan. This also helps avoid concatenation of SQL and VBA, enhances readability and maintainability, and better aligns data types.

**SQL** *(save as a stored query; `PARAMETERS` clause is supported in Access SQL)*

```sql
PARAMETERS prmItemVar Text, prmDatePeg Date;
SELECT SUM(TotQty) AS TotTotQty
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(a.[qty]) AS TotQty
  FROM [dbo_apsplan] a 
  LEFT JOIN [dbo_job_sch] j 
      ON ((a.[ref_line_suf] = j.[suffix]) 
      AND (a.[ref_num] = j.[job]))
  WHERE a.[item] = prmItemVar
    AND a.[is_demand]=1 
    AND DateValue(IIf(a.[ref_type] = 'j', j.[start_date], a.[due_date])
        ) <= prmDatePeg
  
  UNION ALL

  SELECT SUM([qty_ordered] - [qty_shipped]) AS TotQty
  FROM [dbo_coitem]
  WHERE [item] = prmItemVar
    AND [ref_num] IS NULL
    AND ([stat]='o' OR [stat]='p')
    AND DateValue([due_date]) <= prmDatePeg
);
```

**VBA**

```vb
Function DmdQtyThruDate(ItemVar As String, DatePeg As Date) As Double
    Dim qDef   As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst    As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    ' INITIALIZE QUERYDEF
    Set qDef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")    

    ' BIND PARAMETERS
    qDef!prmItemVar = ItemVar
    qDef!prmDatePeg = DatePeg

    ' OPEN RECORDSET
    Set rst = qDef.OpenRecordset()
    If rst.EOF = False Then
       DmdQtyThruDate = Nz(rst("TotTotQty"), 0)
    Else
       DmdQtyThruDate = 0
    End If
    
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing: Set qDef = Nothing

End Function
```